# Need help to split a long string with multiple substrings containing 4 variables

Tags: string, substring

Need help to split a long string with multiple substrings containing 4 variables in SQL Server Studio 2016. The string may contain endless amounts of substring within it.

Current state

[{'actual': 0.0, 'budget': 100.00, 'subcat': 'abd', 'fcc_account': '242120'}, {'actual': 200.00, 'budget': 500.00, 'subcat': 'abc', 'fcc_account': '242123'}]

Desired state

| Actual | Budget | Subcat | FCCAccount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 100.00 | abd | 242120 |
| 200.00 | 500.00 | abc | 242123 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below simple implementation of this -

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '[{"actual": 0.0, "budget": 100.00, "subcat": "abd", "fcc_account": "242120"}, {"actual": 200.00, "budget": 500.00, "subcat": "abc", "fcc_account": "242123"}]'
 SELECT *
 FROM OPENJSON(@json)
 WITH (actual nvarchar(50) , budget nvarchar(50) ,subcat nvarchar(50) ,fcc_account nvarchar(50) )
```

Comment: How do I replace the single quote with double quotes? the table i set my query against is not in a proper format for JSON.

Comment: I think you can replace them from the source from where you get the string. Then pass it to SQL

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it to work. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: Great. please mark my answer if it was useful to you.